# Assign different IPs to different Docker container

Tags: networking, docker, ip

I need to run two containers each containing a script binding on a specific (public) IP (11.11.11.22 and 11.11.11.23)

The docker host itself is on 10.10.10.222.

I have the subnet 11.11.11.20/27, my gateway is 11.11.11.21

If it matters my server is at SoftLayer.

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx-0:
    image: nginx:1.10
    ports:
      - 11.11.11.22:80:80
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: 11.11.11.22

  nginx-1:
    image: nginx:1.10
    ports:
      - 11.11.11.23:80:80
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: 11.11.11.23

networks:
  app_net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 11.11.11.20/27
        gateway: 11.11.11.21
```

*ip a*

---

```
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.10.222/27 brd 10.10.10.223 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 11.11.11.22/32 brd 11.11.11.22 scope global eth1:0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 11.11.11.23/32 brd 11.11.11.23 scope global eth1:1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ips inside container *docker exec nginx-0 ip a*

```
6: eth0@if7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 11.11.11.22/27 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**If I curl the two IPs i get an "curl: (52) Empty reply from server"**

Any other IP in my range will return "Failed to connect..."

Is there any solution to do this?

Thanks in advance!
Dominik

Comment: The default firewall rules for Docker don't allow external access to a container. Exposed ports are used to access a service via the IP of the host. See the [networking documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/articles/networking/) for more details.

Comment: But I want to bind to a specific IP inside of my container, so that's not really my usecase.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I had to remove the interface on the host.

```
ipconfig eth0:0 down
ipconfig eth0:1 down
```

I also removed it from the */etc/networking/interfaces*